# Post parameters with too much nested string quotes

Tags: php, javascript, post

In my PHP website there is a table which is generated dynamically with this code:

```
<tbody>

<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=farm-o-pedia', 'root', '');                                                                      
$db->query("SET NAMES utf8");
query2="select crop_id,crop_name from crop_master order by crop_id";
$result=$db->query($query2)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($result as $row)
{

 print('<tr onclick="window.location.href = \'editdata.php\';"><td>'.$row['crop_id'].'</td><td class="center">'.$row['crop_name'].'</td></tr>');
}



$db=null;
?>
```

Here i want to pass the crop_id of the row which has been clicked. How to attach GET or POST parameters with window.location.href = \'editdata.php\'???

Comment: POST not at all, because that would require a form (or AJAX), but GET parameters you can add just in the normal way, `editdata.php?foo=bar&abc=xyz`.

Comment: Don't use inline Javascript for what you could achieve with a simple `<a>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
print('<tr onclick="window.location.href = \'editdata.php?id='.$row["crop_id"].'\';"><td>'.$row['crop_id'].'</td><td class="center">'.$row['crop_name'].'</td></tr>');
```

If you add into your href ?id=your_id you can retrieve into the page after in GET mode like this:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```